# Is it possible to execute JavaScript in JavaScript include tag?

Tags: javascript, include

Is it possible to do somthing like this ?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='xxx.js'>
    alert('Can I say hello in this area?');
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Purpose is to reduce script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it is possible to do this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='xxx.js'>
    alert('Can I say hello in this area?');
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    eval([].pop.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script')).innerHTML);
</script>
```

It eval's the .innerHTML of the last `script` tag that was closed.

It is also possible to include the eval code in your external file, the last script tag should evaluate to the script tag that initialized the file download.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
    var doesItWork = "#myElement";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("did it work?");
        $(doesItWork).text("yes");
    });
</script>

<div id="myElement">no</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to use a separate `script`, and do not use a self-closing tag, I've wasted many hours figuring out a problem because I used a self-closing script tag.

Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js"></script>
```

NOT

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari so I'm going to say no it's not possible.